# Connection to Reporting service fails in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, authentication

I am trying out **Form authentication in Reporting Service** to work. But not successful. The problem is I can't connect to report server both from Management Studio and Report Manager. 
Actually I am following the steps from http://bharathonsqlserver.blogspot.sg/2012/09/forms-authentication-in-ssrs-2012.html#comment-form.
[image]

Comment: What are you getting for an error when you try to connect to the Report Manager?

Comment: Is Report Manager up?

Comment: I encountered something similar to this....you have to log in locally as the machine admin (not just any admin, the actual machine admin account). Then fire up IE/Edge in Admin mode. Then go into Reporting Service. From their you can permission who can actually get into Reporting Service and what permissions they have once in. If you do not have these permissions, you may need to ask an admin to perform it for you.

Comment: @WEI_DBA I am getting Invalid Server URL. 1st link is the message i got when navigate to report server url and 2nd link is for report manager reportserver http://i66.tinypic.com/2m5xq8h.jpg 
http://i67.tinypic.com/2ez6z9i.jpg

Comment: @Chris I have done with elevated mode exactly like what you hv suggested and I have full admin right and log-in as Machine's admin . But I still cannot log in.

Comment: I am thinking like ..this error arise because I haven't successfully install SQL ? I am getting many repair fail error. However I can still connect to my local Database Engine and Reporting Service(if I use window authentication) http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/sql-2012-developer-edition-repair-fails

Comment: Have you gone into Reporting Services Configuration Manager and configured the URLs for both the Manager and Reports?

Comment: @WEI_DBA  yup, I have done it for both of them.

Comment: So, while you were in the Configuration Manager, did you connect to the URLs successfully for the Manager and Reports?

Comment: @WEI_DBA    I can only have access to UI login aspx pages as in they display perfectly. But only then I am getting error when I put in credentials to connect to report server database.

Comment: Could you please add your environment to the question. Where is SSRS installed (Server/Client)? Where are you accessing the URL from (Server/Client)? Does your environment have an Active Directory? Are you logging in with your AD account or with a SQL Server account? If the permissions are ok, then one thing I have noticed is that you have to start SSMS with administrative permissions to be able to log in to an SSRS instance.